# Metric Between Groups

Tags: group-theory, metric-spaces

I was curious if there is a coherent definition of the "distance'' between two groups. I know that the [word metric](http://A%20Course%20in%20Formal%20Languages,%20Automata%20and%20Groups,) exists between elements of the same group $G$, but given two groups (say the permutations groups of different sizes $G_1=S_n, G_2= S_m, m\not=n$) is there a coherent notion of a distance $D(G_1, G_2)$ that is of any utility? As they are both metrics we could maybe use a [Gromov-Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov%E2%80%93Hausdorff_convergence) type of distance, but my searches haven't yielded anything.

Thanks!

To clarify: either a function $G_1\times G_2:\to[0,\infty)$ that satisfies the typical metric properties or if you want to metrize the groups a function $(G_1,d_1)\times (G_2,d_2)\to[0,\infty)$ is fine too.

Comment: There is certainly an analogue of the Gromov-Hausdorff metric for compactly metrized groups (= pairs $(G,d)$ with $G$ a group and $d$ a metric inducing a compact topology on $G$ with respect to which the group and inverse operations of $G$ are continuous). Namely, given two compactly metrized groups $\mathcal{G}=(G,d), \mathcal{G}'=(G',d')$ we can consider the infimum over all pairs $f,f'$ of isometric group homomorphisms of $\mathcal{G},\mathcal{G}'$ respectively into a single compactly metrized group $\mathcal{H}=(H,e)$ of the usual Hausdorff distance of the images $f[G], f'[G']$ in $(H,e)$.

Comment: (Note that isometric group homomorphisms are injective.) But it's not clear to me that that does anything interesting, ultimately (although note that it generalizes to arbitrary types of compactly metrized structures, e.g. rings, fields, ...). Also, it's not a metric on groups, or even compactly topologizable groups, but rather groups endowed with a specific choice of compact metric.

Comment: You should clarify what you are looking for and why do you restrict to groups: Are you asking for a function $G_1\times G_2\to [0,\infty)$ satisfying some metric inequalities? Or, are you looking for a function $D((G_1,d_1), (G_2,d_2))\in [0,\infty)$?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Either is fine; I was deliberately vague. I guess a slight preference on for a function $G_1\times G_2\to[0,\infty)$ satisfying metric properties